# Multiple sequential exec tasks in a single bash script

Tags: php, bash, exec, avconv

I'm trying to run the following two tasks in a bash script being triggered from a php script. Both of these are executing correctly when I comment out the other so it's obviously the way I've incorrectly laid out the complete job.

They should be run sequentially, not in parallel, so the first exec needs to finish before the second one starts...

I should also note that the variables are being passed through from the php script that is triggering it (in case it's relevant).

```
#!/bin/bash

Udata1=$1
Udata2=$2

#Encode incoming audio file to 128k MP3 using avconv
exec avconv - i /var/www/html/tracks/$Udata1/$Udata2 -ab 128k /var/www/html/tracks/$Udata1/serve/$Udata2.128k.mp3;

#Encode 128k MP3 generated above to WAV using avconv
exec avconv -i /var/www/html/tracks/$Udata1/serve/$Udata2.128k.mp3 /varwww/html/dump/$Udata2.wav

exit;
```

I guess what I'm utlimately asking is how to run multiple exec's in the same .sh script?

Comment: `a bash script being triggered from a php script` be sure that you are *very* aware of the security implications of doing this.

Comment: Yes I'm fully aware thanks. The php firing this is being called via an include on a totally different php page. It's not like this is just sitting there on the webserver for vistors to click on. Sure somebody that knew what they were doing and looking for could violate it, but isn't that the case with any website really? I appreciate the advice though.

Comment: Configuring PHP to allow it to execute an operating system process is much less secure than configuring it not to.  In that situation I usually set a flag (in a database, file system, etc as appropriate) or push something onto a message queue to trigger the external process to run, rather than directly starting a process.

Comment: That's a clever idea, hadn't thought of that. So kind of like a cron job that waits for something to tell it to run?

Comment: cron is a fine way to do that.

Comment: Thanks Eric, putting that on my to-do list! All of this is just being built and tested on a small cloud VPS at the moment, not a fully functioning website, so I guess I was being a bit too flippant with regards to security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` replaces the currently running process with the spawned process. It never returns. You can't `exec` two things like that.

That said you don't need to. Just remove `exec` from those two lines and it should work fine.

Comment: Bang! :) Ok so you taught me something crucial today! Thank you so much Etan! Would the same apply if I was to run a mixture of different programs in the same script too?

Comment: Yes. What you are running doesn't matter. A command is a command and blocks the script until it finishes unless you put it in the background or it puts itself in the background.

Comment: I did think that commands block the script in order while they are being run but it's great to have it confirmed! Thanks man ;)